# Can I prevent a non-template class from being instantiated?

Tags: c++, c++11

C++11 provides extern template declarations to prevent instances of template classes from being instantiated in the current compilation unit.  Is there any way to do the same for a non-templatized class declared in a header file without modifying the header file in which it was declared?

The motivation is reducing object file bloat caused by boost, which defines a significant number of non-templatized classes in headers only even where inlining can't apply.

Comment: Why do you care about object file size? Your linker should de-dup any identical symbols during linking.

Comment: @ildjarn: Multiple compilation of identical symbols can cause a huge compilation time in big projects

Comment: @Paranaix: Precompiled headers take care of that, without needing any hack like this question asks for.

Comment: A non-template class is already a class. What instantiation do you want to prevent?

Comment: Examples of instantiated symbols include the destructor, vtable, and typeinfo for the boost::bad_function_call exception.

Answer (score 0):

For most intents and purposes, there aren't really any tricks to this.  Unless a precompiled header is a trick?  Doing the leg work to move dependencies out of headers is what I would recommend.

My experience with trying to fix these sorts of things is that it usually is a symptom of  library dependencies within *your* project being out of control.  Everything depends on everything else, so it's hard not to include it all.  So when you include the wrong header it affects everything.

Visualize your dependencies and if it isn't a [DAG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph), then that is your first concern.

After that it should be easier to identify specific headers that are causing problems.  The [pimpl idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pimpl_idiom) and predeclarations are good tools for correcting minutia.

I haven't had consistent problems with boost, though some of their libraries can be trouble makers.  `boost::multi_index` is the only one that I can think of offhand.